# library class extends Application not called by manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have a class MyProject extends Application which is part of a library project.
I need to get `onCreate` called before other activities start. Therefore I put it to the librarys AndroidManifest

```
<application
            android:name=".MyProject.MyProject"
...
```

Problem is that the gradle build process takes the application definition from the main application AndroidManifest. onCreate does not get called.

I also tried to change the application part of the projects manifest. Then I run into another problem. The package context does not fit to my library.
This part of the onCreate `stackBuilder.addParentStack(someOtherClass.class);` 
throws a ActivityNotFoundException.

My question is: Where and how to put code into an android library project that is called automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you can create a class in your main application that will extend `MyProject` (without adding any more code as you don't need more). Then you can declare your new class in the manifest.

Comment: Some times you will need to implement it in several places in The Manifest:
<application
        android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="MyAppClass" >
            <action android:name="com.example.MyAppClass" />
        </activity>

Comment: @Szymon how to add that class in manifest?. what tag i need to use to define it in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Application class is served as singleton where we can initialize some stuff. You should take a look at initializing the most popular libraries. The answer is using static method. For example:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Library.initialize(this); //Entry point
    }
}
```